# Get parent category class in post_class()

Tags: css, post-class

I am trying to add the parent category class in post_class() of some posts from one of my subcatgories. I have an advanved theme so I need to style all the posts from the parent cateogry using it's class, not the subcategory class (too much hassle in CSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
function mytheme_get_post_class_parent_cats() {
    $parent_cat_classes = array();
    // Get parent categories
    $post_cats = wp_get_post_categories();
    // Loop through post categories
    foreach ( $post_cats as $post_cat ) {
        $cat_parents = get_category_parents( $post_cat , false, ',', true );
        // if there are any parent categories
        if ( $cat_parents ) {
            // create an array
            $cat_array = explode( $cat_parents, ',' );
            // First key of the array is the top-level category parent
            $parent_cat_id = $cat_array[0];
            // Get the name of the top-level parent category
            $parent_cat = get_cat_name( $parent_cat_id );
            // create the CSS class .category-parent-{categoryname}
            $parent_cat_classes[] = 'category-parent-' . $parent_cat;
        } else {
            // Otherwise, the category is a top-level cat, so use it
            $cat_name = get_cat_name( $post_cat );
            $parent_cat_classes[] = 'category-parent-' . $cat_name;
        }
    }
    // Return CSS class, or false
    return $parent_cat_classes;
}
```

Then, when you call `post_class()`:

```
<?php post_class( mytheme_get_post_class_parent_cats() ); ?>
```

- Codex ref: [wp_get_post_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories)
- Codex ref: [get_category_parents()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents)
- Codex ref: [get_cat_name()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your function, it's not working o_O

Comment: It's example code for implementing the two referenced functions. Can you provide more detail? What's not working.

Comment: as this is for a post, the function should loop through the post's categories: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories

Comment: Okay, see updates. Added parameters to `get_category_parents()`, and added an `explode()` call to create the array from which to get the top-level parent category.

Comment: Oh, good call, @michael! Let me adjust things a bit...

Comment: Okay, one more edit: uses `wp_get_post_categories()`, loops through each ID returned, and determines its parent category, then adds it to the array.

Comment: Sorry, but it just echoes the normal classes now.

Comment: Hello @Chip. You're not using `post_class` filter, is there any reason not to use it?

Comment: @Mamaduka no reason, as far as I remember; that's probably an equally valid implementation!

Answer (score 0):

A friend found the perfect solution, so I think it's fair to share it with you guys:

```
function rats_class($classes){
 global $post;
 $cat=get_the_category(get_query_var('post'));
 if(is_array($cat)&&!empty($cat)){
  if($cat[0]->category_parent!=0){
   $parents=get_category_parents($cat[0]->term_id,false,'@',true);
   if(!empty($parents)){
    $parent=explode('@',$parents);
    $classes[]='category-'.$parent[0];
   }
  }
 }
 return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class','rats_class');
```